# Yum lock file problem

Tags: centos, yum

When there are more than 1 copies of yum running, I get this error:

```
Another app is currently holding the yum lock; waiting for it to exit
```

Is there a way to make yum just exit the first time it can't get the lock rather than stay open waiting for it?

Comment: Yum is open source so I can say with 100% certainty yes you can, how to do it though is a matter of talking to a dev.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's a specific command option to do that.  You could use the -R option to specify the maximum amount of time that yum will wait, but it's specified in minutes so you'd have to wait at least a minute.

Comment: Yeh, I had seen that option, I was just hoping there was some configuration option that I had missed to stop yum from doing it at all

Answer (score 0):

**You do not want to do this..**

There is a reason it needs a lock and it waits..

The problem with package managers, is that they need to be **run only once** because of the dependancies of other packages...

```
You will most probably run into serious concurrency problems if you do this..
```

**Its highly suggested you dont change this in the code...**

"ctl + c" will solve your problem..

Comment: You misunderstood, I actually wanted the second yum to exit rather than just wait forever for the first yum to quit.